# Printing value of a *big.Int field in a Go struct

Tags: go, overflow

I have a big.Int I need to store inside of a struct, but when I try to do so it overflows. Code example below

```golang
type NumberStore struct {
  mainnumber *big.Int
 }
var ledger NumberStore
// In decimal this is 33753000000000000000
var largehex string = "1D46ABEAB3FC28000"
myNumber := new(big.Int)
myNumber.SetString(largehex, 16)
ledger.mainnumber = myNumber
fmt.Println(ledger)// Prints 0xc0000a64c0, but I need it to be 33753000000000000000
```

Comment: Export the member variable: declare it capitalized `Mainnumber`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `mainnumber` is a pointer field in your `NumberStore` struct, printing out the struct by default will just print out the value of the pointer, not the value it points to.

As the comment says, if you make your field exported then `fmt.Println` will show the underlying value; but if you don't need it exported, then `fmt.Println(ledger.mainnumber)` should print the number you expect. Here's your full code with one line added at the end:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

type NumberStore struct {
    mainnumber *big.Int
}

func main() {

    var ledger NumberStore
    // In decimal this is 33753000000000000000
    var largehex string = "1D46ABEAB3FC28000"
    myNumber := new(big.Int)
    myNumber.SetString(largehex, 16)
    ledger.mainnumber = myNumber
    fmt.Println(ledger)
    fmt.Println(ledger.mainnumber)
}
```

[Run on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1pd0kzettB7), it prints:

```
{0xc000092000}
33753000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

By printing like this `fmt.Println(ledger)`, you're relying on the default formatting of the value `ledger`. For each field in the struct, it will only print the default representation of that value, unless it can access the appropriate custom formatting code for that type. For `mainnumber` of type `*big.Int`, that is "pointer to big.Int", it's simply printing the pointer address.

In order to give `fmt` access to the custom string formatting code for a `*big.Int` value, you either need to pass it directly: `fmt.Println(ledger.mainnumber)`, or change `mainnumber` to an exported field, like this:

```golang
type NumberStore struct {
    Mainnumber *big.Int
}
```

The `fmt` package cannot automatically find the value's formatting code (the `.String() string` method) if it is an unexported struct field.